# remove a parent element of the input element provided

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

html form :

```
<span id="contactSpan" class="repeatEntry">
<ul>
   <div id="contactSpan-1" class="subSpan-1">
      <li>
          <input type="text" id="contactname-1" name="contactname-1" class="contactname"                title="Enter your Full Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['contactname']?>"/>
      </li>
      <li>
           <input id="contactemail-1" type="email" name="contactemail-1" class="contactemail" title="Enter your email address" value="<?php echo $_POST['contactemail']?>"/>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input id="contactmobile-1" type="tel" name="contactmobile-1" class="contactmobile" value="<?php echo $_POST['contactmobile']?>"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type="button" class="remove-this-button" style="display:None" id="remove-this-button-1" name="remove-this-button-1" value="Remove contact">
      </li>
   </div>
</ul>
</span>
<input type="button" class="addMore" id="addContact" name="addContact" value="Add another contact">
```

I am trying to clone complete < div> class. I am able to clone it. Initially, "Remove contact" button is not dispalyed, but then in the clone elements it will be displayed.

"Remove contact " is not working for me, with the click of this button, am trying to remove the entire parent < div> class which was cloned.

Code Sample :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var idIncrement = 1;
$(function () {

//remove div class function  -- not Woking

  function removeDiv(){
    alert("check123");
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  }


// cloning the entire contact "div" -- Working

  $('input.addMore').on('click', function () {
        idIncrement++;
        var $table = $('#contactSpan');
        var $tr = $table.find('div').eq(0).clone();
        $tr.appendTo($table).find('input').val('');

        $tr.appendTo($table).find(".remove-this-button").removeAttr("style");
        $tr.appendTo($table).find(".remove-this-button").attr("value", "Remove Contact").on("click", removeDiv);
        $tr.appendTo($table).find(".remove-this-button").attr("name","remove-this-button-"+idIncrement);        
        $tr.appendTo($table).find(".remove-this-button").attr("id","remove-this-button-"+idIncrement);
    });

});

</script>
```

It is able to remove style attribute from remove-button, and on click it is also calling the function removeDiv. Alert is triggered on the removeDiv function.
But then only remove() part is not working.

Comment: parent() just check for one level ancestor, you need to use closest() as in mplungjan's answer.

Comment: As a side note, your HTML markup is invalid, DIV cannot be direct child of a UL element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of your duplicated appendTo and find. Try only append once
Also your $tr is a div, not a row and the container is a span not a div. the resulting html is not valid. In any case you want .closest to travel up the tree

```
 $tr.appendTo($table).find(".remove-this-button")
   .on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('div').remove(); 
   })
   .attr("value", "Remove Contact")
```

Comment: @dreamer now you have to fix your HTML because it is invalid and sooner or later you could have serious issue with that

Answer (score 0):

[parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) is the solution for you.

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) return immediate parent only.

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2tfe/)

try this:

```
$(this).parents('div').remove();
```

as point out parents will return you all the parent div so for getting first div try:

```
$(this).parents('div')[0].remove();
```

Comment: No, parents('div') will return all ancestor DIVs. What if there is more than one parent DIV? `.parents('div').first()` could be a solution but then better to use `.closest('div')`

Comment: can filter with class or any other identifier, the point here is to make understand difference in parent and parents